# Wicket PageParameters Interfere with Page's Model Object

Tags: java, parameters, model, wicket, textfield

I have a simple page with a form that includes a TextField. I have set the model object (Serializable POJO) with a single variable called **containerId**.  No matter if I use a LoadableDetachableModel or the standard Model.of(), if I have a PageParameter also named **containerId** then the form model behavior breaks causing the value to always remain as what the PageParameter value is set.  If I change the page parameter name to **container** and pass that value into my model on initialization the problem goes away.  Has anyone else experienced this? If you can provide any details as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the conflict is in the URL that is produced when you submit the form.  I would speculate that your page is mounted in such a way that the PageParameters are encoded as query parameters in the URL, and that the form is submitted via a GET which therefore encodes its values as query parameters in the URL.  Thus two query parameters with the same name get added, and one of them is lost.

So, there are at least two options you can try:

1. Change the form to POST (add method="POST" to the HTML)
2. Mount the page in a way that encodes the page parameters differently, for example with something like the following:

   mountPage("/page/${containerId}", YourPageClass.class);

Comment: Yet another way to work it around is to override TextField#getInputName() and return something unique (it is up to you to decide what that could be).